# Link budget - Path-Loss in a Wlan Network

Tags: wireless, distance, loss

I am struggeling with the dB calculation on an wlan-network. An antenna has dBi but the pathloss in the air is dB with the formula 100 + 20 * log(km). Can I just mix dB, dBi and dBm?

Here is a sample I calculated (where i haven't a solution): 
This is a connection between two buildings with 10km space between them. This means 120dB loss according to the formula on top. The antenna has a gain of 18.5 dBi and a cable between the antenna and AP has a loss of 1.5 dB.

This means a loss of 103 dB. Is 103 dB the correct dimension?

The allowed EIRP in Switzerland is 20dBm. This means ouput of the AP is 20dBm - 18.5 dBi + 1.5 dB = 3 dBi or 2 mW.

The signal level at the receiver is thereof 20 dB - 120 dB = -100 dBm or 1 / 10^10 mW.

Is this correct or am I missing something important?

Comment: This _might_ be a better question on the [Signal Processing Stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am coming from network and they telling me go to electrical :D

Comment: LOL well there is a Networking SE, true but there is also a Signal Processing SE, which is different from the Networking SE :) The SPSE is more mathematical whereas the Networking SE is more about servers and concepts of... well... computer networking like UART, IPv4, and other various fundamentals.

Comment: Almost everything about your calculations is wrong (sorry, not trying to be mean).  Free space path loss is frequency dependent, not just distance dependent.  Link budget is calculated as tx power out + tx antenna gain - tx cable loss - free space loss - rx cable loss + rx antenna gain + rx receiver sensitivity.  There are many online link budget calculators and related questions with answers if this search the existing material in EE SE.

Comment: it is meant to be for 2.4GHz and the free space loss is 20 * log(km) as a simpler formula. This formula use my teacher at the university.

Comment: You should update the question with the frequency and any other additional info you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just mix dB, dBi and dBm?

Yes you can. For instance, when you said the pathloss was 120 dB but you had a 18.5 dBi antenna, you are OK with then assuming the pathloss is improved to 101.5 dB tempered by another 1.5 dB for cable loss bringing the total to 103 dB path loss.

EDITED section: -

When it comes to 20 dBm EIRP (Effective Isotropic Radiated Power) what it means is that you can't use all the power of 20 dBm in one direction (one lobe) therefore, with an antenna of gain 18.5 dB you can only transmit 1.5 dBm.

In your example, the power at the receiver antenna is 103 dB lower than 20 dBm or -83 dBm (as would be picked up by an isotropic antenna). However, if you used a receive antenna with a gain of 18.5 dBi, the received power will be -64.5 dBm.

Comment: I think the antenna gain is included in the EIRP? This means there is a pathloss from 120 dBm

Comment: @thomas I made a mistake originally about EIRP that I have now corrected. However, it doesn't affect pathloss; I'm only using your example to show that you can add dBi to dB. For a receive antenna you get the full benefit!

Answer (score 1):

Given 10,000 meters path length, at 2.4GHz where wavelength is 12.5cm, the path has 10,000 / 0.125 = 80,000 wavelengths.

The formula I've used is

PathLoss = 22dB + 10*log10[ (distance / wavelength)^2  ]

Pathloss = 22dB + 10*log10[ 80,000^2 ]

pathloss = 22dB + 20 * log10[ 80,000 ]

pathloss = 22dB + 20 * 4.9 = 22 + 98 == 120dB

As others have discussed, antennas can be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above calculation that the power at the receiver would be -83 dBm and the receiver gain would be added to that. In general the received power can be calculated using Friis Equation.

Pr = (Pt)*(Gt)*(Gr)*(lambda/(4*pi*d))^2

Pr = (0.1)*(50.119)*(1)*(0.125/(4*3.14*10000))^2

Pr = 4.9641e-012 Watts

Pr = -113.04 dBW

Pr = -83.042 dBm

Which agrees with the above calculation.

Note to convert from log scale to linear scale simply use the formula:

linear_value = 10^(dB_value/10)